# Airflow - Error when scheduling airflow script to run on specific days of the week

Tags: cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to have an airflow script to be scheduled to run every Tuesday at 9:10 AM UTC. Given below is how I have defined it.

```
dag = DAG(
dag_id=DAG_NAME,
default_args=args,
schedule_interval="10 9 * * 2",
catchup=False
```

I however find that when the time comes, the script does not get triggered automatically. However if I do not have the value defined in the day column (last column), the scheduler works fine. Any idea where I am going wrong.

Thanks

**Update:**

```
args = {
'owner': 'admin',
'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(9)
}

dag = DAG(
dag_id=DAG_NAME,
default_args=args,
schedule_interval = "10 9 * * 2",
catchup = False
)
```

Comment: Airflow starts a job when the assigned period is *over*. Since there is no start_date included in the question: This might be connected to the fact that you need to have a start_date at least one week in the past.

Comment: You should avoid using a variable start_date https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date. The other problem is that start_date is derived from min(start_date) so after you change it you will need to clear out all DAG runs to reset the true start date.

Can you do that and then hardcode the start_date to 2 Tuesdays in the past?

Answer (score 0):

This one stumps people more than anything else in Airflow, but as commenter and Airflow documentation [state](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/scheduler.html#scheduling-triggers),

> The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

In this case you can either bump back your DAG `start_date` one `schedule_interval` or wait for the next `schedule_interval` to complete.

Comment: I have edited my initial message with the updated arguments that I pass. I have used a start date that is 9 days prior to the current date and still it did not trigger. Is there anything else that I could do to have this run. Tnx